# how to plot after combining rows dplyr

Tags: r, plot, dplyr

I'm using the babynames dataset by Hadley Wickham. I'm trying to plot a graph showing the top popular boys name in 1950 using dplyr. So far I can show to the top names by:

```
malebabynames1950<-filter(babynames, year==1950, gender=="M")
totalboys1950<-malebabynames1950 %>% group_by(name, gender, year) %>% summarise(count=sum(count))
head(arrange(totalboys1950, desc(count)))
```

which shows:

```
    name gender  year count
    <chr>  <chr> <int> <int>
1   James      M  1950 86266
2  Robert      M  1950 83590
3    John      M  1950 79447
4 Michael      M  1950 65185
5   David      M  1950 60761
6 William      M  1950 60722
```

but I cannot figure out how to plot names vs count. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use ggplot with `geom_bar`. By default, `geom_bar` uses `stat="count"` so you don't have to group and summarize before plotting. If you want to use your grouped dataframe for plotting, use `geom_bar(stat="identity")`